# How to apply jQuery Sortable to li and li child tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have one `ul` table which need to be sortable. I am able perform drag-drop / sortable using `li` but I want to perform it using `.drag` class which has `a` tag.

Below is sample working HTML.

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="li" id="1">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button close"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button drag"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li" id="2">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button close"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button drag"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li" id="3">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button close"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button drag"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;">Item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I perform sortable on `a` tag's `.drag` class?

I have tried with `items: ' > a'` and `handle: '.drag'` but no luck.

If it is possible to do that then it should look same like we do for `li` tag.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

I am able to drag using li but not using a tag.

Comment: Can you please try to add this to jsfiddle.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, I want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3kdSZ/4/) kind of functionality but it's not working

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, I don't have an account in jsfiddle :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
// Sort the parents
$(".ui-sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".drag",
    cursor: "move",
});

// Sort the children
$(".lines").sortable({
    containment: ".container",
    items: "> .item",
    connectWith: '.lines'
});
```

I changed only the <li> elements class (just because I don't like classes named after elements).

Comment: Hi @Savedario, Your example is working little. It does not gives feeling of dragging. In your sample jsfiddle, it's working but on same on my development.

Comment: Perhaps you care to reformulate your question?

Comment: Your jsfiddle example is perfectly working but curious that same is not working on my code. That's what I am looking. As soon as it get I let you know.

Comment: I have set same structure as you have but still something is messing.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the part of the code that you did not include in your question. If you want help, please edit your question and add the relevant parts.